# Firebase Firestore Database Using JS Error : Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: doc is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm currently working on my project that uses Firebase Firestore database system from Google. In the beginning, I just add some code from Firebase to initialize it and also some code to getting the document from it. So, my initial plan is basic which is getting the document from the database then add it to the HTML document. At the beginning after initialization, and accessing the database within a const named "db" there's no problem like in the title ("Referenceerror...") and if I tested it in console, it will show my data from database correctly. But after I add some JS code to DOM and add the data to HTML, the error showed up. Can someone please help me? I'm really newbie in this case of Firebase. But, yes, I've searched for this problem throughout many forums and finds nothing.Here's some part of my HTML and JS code

1.) HTML

```
<script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyARW1T5mnayv7XVsHnfP_uc0jO-ck11ykw",
        authDomain: "sde-sale-stock.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://sde-sale-stock.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "sde-sale-stock",
        storageBucket: "sde-sale-stock.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "247739189879",
        appId: "1:247739189879:web:0f809640941c5d3e341472",
        measurementId: "G-VS6QCRD18K"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
    const db = firebase.firestore();

</script>
<script src="js-in1.js"></script>
```

> 2.) JS

```
//DOMstart
const docTarget = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

function insertDoc(){
        //creation
    let box = document.createElement('div');
    let header = document.createElement('h4');
    let hargaBeli = document.createElement('p');
    let p2 = document.createElement('p');
    let hargaJual = document.createElement('p');
    let p4 = document.createElement('p');

    //insertion
    box.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    header.textContent = doc.data().name;
    hargaBeli.innerHTML = "HB";
    p2.textContent = doc.data().HB;
    hargaJual.innerHTML = "HJ";
    p4.textContent = doc.data().HJ;

    //naming
    box.classname = "box";
    header.className = "title-box";
    hargaBeli.className = "tc-1";
    p2.className = "tc-2";
    hargaJual.className = "tc-3";
    p4.className = "tc-4";

    //box-naming plus deletion ops
    hitung++;
    box.className = "box " + hitung;
    box.onclick = function(){
                        if (confirm('Apa kamu yakin mau menghapus produk ini?')) {
                            this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
                        } else {
                        console.log('Tidak jadi menghapus produk.');
                        }
    }

    //appending...
    box.appendChild(header);
    box.appendChild(hargaJual);
    box.appendChild(p2);
    box.appendChild(hargaBeli);
    box.appendChild(p4);
    docTarget.appendChild(box); 


      console.log(box.className + "Creation Tracker"); //detection
}

    //get doc
    db.collection('Product').get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data());
            insertDoc(doc);
        })
    })
```

Comment: The error is saying the `doc` variable is not defined.  What do you expect it to be instead, and why?

Comment: doc is actually a method. Before writing this project, I watched the YouTube tutorial about this (pretty much the same) but they don't face a problem. So doc isn't a variable but a method so is it needs to be declared? Doc is for accessing the data from Firebase

Comment: Here, in your code, doc is a variable, not a method: `doc.data().name`.  It's not clear at all where you're expecting it to come from.

Comment: Okay, my bad sorry. I'm new in this field. So, what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of your `insertDoc()` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) you don't include any parameter, so, inside the function, `doc` is undefined.

In addition to calling the function with `insertDoc(doc)`, you need to add this `doc` as a parameter to the function, as follows:

```
function insertDoc(doc) {

    //....    

    //insertion
    box.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);  // Now doc is defined
    header.textContent = doc.data().name;

    //....   
}
```